# Android service callback for crashed application

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service managing multiple sockets, when all the clients (activities, applications...) using that service disconnect their connection with it, `onUnbind()` is called, and the service close all it's sockets. But if an application is crashed or forcibly closed, `onUnbind()` never gets called and the service never close those sockets. How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

if you use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` in `bindService()`
close all sockets in onDestroy (need to override in Service class)

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //close here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the below code :

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override  
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) { 
    // unbind your service
    }
});
```